# All new plugins generating 311 chars of unexpected output?

Tags: plugins, errors, installation

At some point, I started getting a message about 311 characters of unexpected output at every plugin activation. The number is always the same, and it happens for every plugin activation, including reactivating plugins that were temporarily deactivated.

The exact message:

> The plugin generated 311 characters of **unexpected output** during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Is this likely to be a problem with a plugin that has extra whitespace in its files or something? I haven't yet gotten any problems with headers already having been sent. Possibly it's related to [the weird 404 errors I get in wp-admin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/469/how-to-eliminate-weird-404-errors-in-wp-admin), but that problem was around long before this unexpected output issue.

Comment: Could you quote error message exactly?

Comment: Added exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it goes like this (relevant steps only):

1. `plugins.php` page calls `activate_plugin()` function.
2. Function starts output buffering.
3. Includes plugin file.
4. Fires `activate_plugin` action.
5. Fires `'activate_' . trim( $plugin )` action.
6. Fires `activated_plugin` action.
7. If buffer is not empty it creates `WP_Error` object and returns it.
8. `plugins.php` page checks for error and displays error message.

So  output happens somewhere between steps 2 and 7. If it comes up for multiple plugins then steps 3 and 5 are safe to exclude, they are plugin-specific.

So it is likely something in either `activate_plugin` or `activated_plugin`. Also actual unwanted output is passed in `WP_Error`object but not used (only its length).

I'd try to dump hooks first, will take bit of extra code in core a bit to get to that output in `WP_Error` object.

Comment: Thanks, Rarst. Problem solved. Dumping hooks using the old (but still usable) [System Information](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/system-information/) plugin led me to the `activated_plugin` hook. [PuSHPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pushpress/) was running code on every activation and causing trouble. I'll report the issue in the plugin's forums. Your pointer is much appreciated!